# Magento layered navigation position

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i bought one theme and i want to fix my layared navigation to work well.
[image]

I need help from which file i have to edit to fix my layered navigation to show after my menu.

Comment: Sorry Иван but we are not sure what it is that you are asking or how to help you. Perhaps you could show us the code that you have tried to change and what problems you are having. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should find correct template file,then override the template within your theme, then finally rearrange the code so that it displays beneath the vertical navigation.  The following may (possibly) work for you.  But I don't know what type of theme you are using.

1. go to your magento backend url, then go to system->configuration->developer then open the debug panel.
2. Change the current configuration scope to 'Main Website'. Upper left corner of config page.
3. This should add some items to the debug panel.  Set template path hints to 'yes'.
4. go back to the website and find the phtml file that controls your nav.
5. copy the file into the theme your using using the same folder structure.
6. edit that code.

PS another solution may be available to alter the layout files of your site.  they get overridden in a similar fashion to phtml files.